# Jquery Web Quiz - how to go to the next question?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is a quiz site that I'm trying to build. After the user chooses an answer, they are presented with a button to move on to the next question. I tried achieving this task by traversing the DOM and using `hide()` and `show()` functions but it has not worked.

HTML

```
<article id="Pdiv">

    <div id="Q1" >
        <p id="cap" class="color"><b>What is the capital of Brazil?</b> </p>

        <p id="A1" class="answer"><button id="a"><b>Brasilia</b></button> <button class="a"><b>Sao Paulo</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q2" >
        <p id="sa" class="color"> <b>How many states are in the USA?</b> </p>
        <p id="A2" class="answer"><button id="b"><b>50</b></button> <button class="b"><b>300</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q3" >
        <p id="pas" class="color"> <b>What is the longest river in the world?</b> </p>
        <p  id="A3" class="answer"><button id="c"><b>The Nile river</b></button> <button class="c"><b>The Amazon river</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q4" >
        <p id="Cap" class="color"> <b>What is the world's deepest river?</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="d"><b>The Congo River</b></button> <button class="d"><b>The Marianas trench</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q5" >
        <p id="caap" class="color"> <b>What is the world's largest rainforest?</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="e"><b>The Amazon rainforest</b></button> <button class="e"><b>The Congo rainforest</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q6" >
        <p id="capp" class="color"> <b>What is the fastest car in the world?</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="f"><b>Bugatti Bolide</b></button> <button class="f"><b>Lamborghini</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q7" >
        <p id="ap" class="color">  <b>What is the most dangerous naturally occuring element?</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="g"><b>Plutonium <i>(Pu)</i></b></button> <button class="g"><b>Polonium <i>(Po)</i></b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q8">
        <p id="pac" class="color"> <b>Who has won the most Grammys?</b></p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="h"><b>Beyonce</b></button> <button class="h"><b>Quincy Jones</b></button> </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q9" >
        <p id="acp" class="color"> <b>What is the most popular social network worldwide</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="i"><b>Facebook</b></button> <button class="i"><b>Tik Tok</b></button></p>
    </div>

    <div id="Q10" >
        <p id="ac" class="color"> <b>Who is the tallest person to ever live?</b> </p>
        <p class="answer"><button id="j"><b>Robert Wadlow</b></button> <button class="j"><b>Yao Ming</b></button></p>
    </div>

</article>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $("div:gt(0)").hide();

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id")) {
            $("div").removeAttr();
            $("div").attr("class", "move");
            $("p").hide();
            $("div").append("<p class='yc'>You are correct!</p>");
            $("div").append("<p><button class='next'><b>Next Question</b></button>");
        } else {
            $("p").hide();
            $("div").append("<p class='inc'>Incorrect</p>");
            $("div").append("<p><button class='incorrect'><b>Try again</b></button></p>");
        }

        $('.incorrect').on("click", function() {
            $("p").show();
            $('.inc').hide();
            $(this).hide();
        })

        $('.next').on("click", function() {
            $("div").on("click", function() {
                if ($(this).attr("class")) {
                    $(this).next().show().prev().hide();
                }
            })
        });
    })
})
```

I tried selecting the `div` element representing the current question slide, using `$(this)`, and then using DOM traversal methods and `hide()` and `show()` functions to move to the next slide after the user chooses to move to the next question. But I was unsuccessful.

Comment: I would store the questions as data and render each next question as the user answers correctly and clicks the Next button. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/8szrm0bu/

Comment: You were actually showing the next question, but it had hidden question text + answers buttons, and shown the next button. @76484 gave you much better approach, when markup is generated in js.

Comment: @76484 I'm extremely grateful for your contribution. I'm only a year in my self taught developers journey and your solution gave me a headache lol but I understand a little more each day that I've analyzed it. Any recommendations on how to learn web development more efficiently?

Comment: @Yannick You're welcome. Software development is not easy and the (not so) secret to writing good code is to write a lot of bad code - and learn from it. Posting here is a good way to get great help. Similarly, there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - where you can get in-depth reviews of your working code. Feedback is crucial so that you don't unknowingly build bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way to approach this sort of problem is to track the variables that change with a `state` object and then write a function that will render the application according to the current state. I find this much easier than trying to do hiding and showing of elements in different pieces of the code. I try to give my event listeners the task of updating the state and then calling the render function.

I would also store the questions in code in a convenient data structure. This will make it much easier to add/change questions and options. It may even be helpful to use a templating library, like [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), to render the question.

I think we should store the current `screen` state so that we know whether we are showing the user the correct, incorrect or next question screen. (You may even want to create a screen for the completed state.)

The event listeners will listen for clicks on the answers ([delegated](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), due to the fact that they are rendered dynamically) and the Next Question and Try Again buttons. Theses buttons will update the `screen` to be showed to the user (and increment the question `index`, if necessary) and then call `render()`.

The final code is:

```js
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is the capital of Brazil?',
    options: ['Brasilia', 'Sao Paulo'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
     question: 'How many states are in the USA?',
     options: [50, 300],
     answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the longest river in the world?',
    options: ['The Nile river', 'The Amazon river'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the world\'s deepest river?',
    options: ['The Congo River', 'The Marianas trench'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the world\'s largest rainforest?',
    options: ['The Amazon rainforest', 'The Congo rainforest'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the fastest car in the world?',
    options: ['Bugatti Bolide', 'Lamborghini'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the most dangerous naturally occuring element?',
    options: ['Plutonium', 'Polonium'],
    answerIndex: 1
  },
  {
    question: 'Who has won the most Grammys?',
    options: ['Beyonce', 'Quincy Jones'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the most popular social network worldwide',
    options: ['Facebook', 'Tik Tok'],
    answerIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is the tallest person to ever live?',
    options: ['Robert Wadlow', 'Yao Ming'],
    answerIndex: 0
  }
];

const SCREEN = {
  COMPLETE: 'complete',
  CORRECT: 'correct',
  INCORRECT: 'incorrect',
  QUESTION: 'question'
}

const state = {
  questionIndex: 0,
  score: 0,
  screen: SCREEN.QUESTION
};

const questionTemplate = Handlebars.compile(`
  <p class="color">
    <b>{{question}}</b>
  </p>
  <p class="answer">
    {{#each options as |option|}}
      <button data-option type="button">
        <b>{{option}}</b>
      </button>
    {{/each}}
  </p>
`);

const $complete = $('#Complete');
const $correct = $('#Correct');
const $incorrect = $('#Incorrect');
const $question = $('#Question');

const render = () => {
  const screen = state.screen;
  
  if (screen === SCREEN.COMPLETE) {
    $complete.html(`<p>You scored ${state.score} out of ${questions.length}.</p>`);
  } else if (screen === SCREEN.QUESTION) {
    const question = questions[state.questionIndex];
    $question.html(questionTemplate(question));
  }
  
  $complete.toggle(screen === SCREEN.COMPLETE);
  $correct.toggle(screen === SCREEN.CORRECT);
  $incorrect.toggle(screen === SCREEN.INCORRECT);
  $question.toggle(screen === SCREEN.QUESTION);
};

$('#Quiz').on('click', '[data-option]', function () {
  const optionIndex = $(this).index();
  const currentQuestion = questions[state.questionIndex];
  const isCorrect = optionIndex === currentQuestion.answerIndex;
  const isComplete = isCorrect && state.questionIndex === questions.length - 1;
  
  if (isComplete) {
    state.score += 1;
    state.screen = SCREEN.COMPLETE;
  } else if (isCorrect) {
    state.score += 1;
    state.screen = SCREEN.CORRECT;
  } else {
    state.screen = SCREEN.INCORRECT;
  }
  
  render();
});

$('.next').on('click', function () {
  state.questionIndex += 1;
  state.screen = SCREEN.QUESTION;

  render();
});

$('.retry').on('click', function () {
  state.screen = SCREEN.QUESTION;
  render();
});

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="Quiz">
  <div id="Complete" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="Question" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="Correct" style="display:none;">
    <p>You are correct!</p>
    <p>
      <button class="next"><b>Next Question</b></button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="Incorrect" style="display:none;">
    <p>Incorrect</p>
    <p>
      <button class="retry">
        <b>Try again</b>
      </button>
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```